# Unable to open pkpass on an iOS device

Tags: ios, passbook, wallet

Unable to open pkpass when I try I get the error "The pass “pass.pkpass” could not be opened".

When I try to open it in a simulator it works so I don't have a way to debug it. Any ideas?

Comment: Your link is a 404.

Comment: updated. Thanks for letting me know. @PassKit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your pass is failing to load because your web service URL is not being served over HTTPS.

```
error   21:40:19.322330 +0800   Pass Viewer scheme of webServiceURL 'http://xxx.yyy-qa.com:8091/api/' needs to be an https rather than http.
```

To fix, either serve your web service over HTTPS, or hook your phone up to Xcode, enable developer mode, then check the option to allow HTTP for passes.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that!

Comment: using Https worked I can open the pass. Thank you again.

Comment: No problem - maybe remove or disable that link for privacy and if the answer solved your problem then please accept so it helps others

Comment: @ PassKit  can you please have alook on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59069438/how-to-open-a-pkpass-file-to-wallet-from-xamarin-mobile-application